# Change a List item's background in Typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a page, where in the top, there's a question, and below that, there's a list of answers, and you can add new answers too. (image below)
[image]

In a format like **(name of the user who answered)** "válasza: ekkor: (date), which means **his answer, at this time.**
Below every question there are **3 buttons, + C and -**, the ppl who asked the question can **accept the answer (+), deny the answer (-) and cancel applying or denying (C)**.
Problem is, if I press any button for example in any row, the effect only applies to the first one.
**Accept -> Green Background, Deny -> red, C -> white**

**Here's the HTML code:**

```
<div class="container" style="...">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li id="colorTarget" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of actualComments">

                <div style="...">
                    <b>{{comment.iro}}</b> válasza, ekkor: {{comment.mikor}} {{comment.leir}}
                </div><br/>

                <div class="row" style="width:120px;">
                    <div style="...">
                        <button class="btn btn-light" id="buttonTarget1" (click)="acceptAnswer(comment.iro,comment.mikor,comment.leir)">
                        +
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="...">
                        <button class="btn btn-light" id="buttonTarget2" (click)="clearAnswer(comment.iro,comment.mikor,comment.leir)">
                        C
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="...">
                        <button class="btn btn-light" id="buttonTarget3" (click)="denyAnswer(comment.iro,comment.mikor,comment.leir)">
                         -
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**And the TypeScript:**

```
acceptAnswer(iro, mikor, iras) {
    var x = this.answerid(iro, mikor, iras);         
    this.actualComments[x].accepted = 1;
    var target = document.getElementById("colorTarget");
    target.style.background = 'green';
    target.style.color = 'white';
  }
```

Deny and Clear Answer functions are exactly like this, but with red and white color.
If you have any idea..please.

So, in short: unique id to all `li` and pass this unique id to the functions.

Comment: You are getting an element with id `greenTarget`, where is that? You are going to have to generate a unique id for each `li` in the list if you want to do what I think you are trying.

Comment: @R.Richards Oh I'm sorry, that's just a a bad copy paste. Updated my post, its colorTarget in the function too

Comment: Then the issue is what I mentioned. You need a unique id for each `li` in the `ngFor` loop. Without that, the `document.getElementById("colorTarget");` will just grab the first one each time.

Comment: @R.Richards I see. But I'm new in TS, so .. if you could suggest any example for this unique id for each li.. (where I dont have to use JQuery) I'd be very grateful

Comment: I am thinking that you could use a combination of `iro`, `mikor`, and `iras`. Maybe, concat the values together to create the id. And, since you are passing those values into the functions you call, you can rebuild the id when you look for the element to change. Does that give you a good direction to go in? I could code up a possible answer in a bit, if you like.

Comment: @R.Richards please.. :) I'm not sure how could I get the li's id, from the values in it :/

Comment: @R.Richards Here's a stackblitz link, if you need. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iaduxf

Comment: Thank you, both of you, I'll continue this tomorrow. Another part is that the actualComment.accepted represent the accept/deny/clear colors, and when the user navigates to the page the comments load already with their "accept type" (already accepted comments will be green right after the page loads...etc.) After it's done I'll accept the easier answer :) But really, thank you, both of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use CSS classes on `li` elements:

```
<div class="container" style="...">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li id="colorTarget" 
        class="list-group-item {{ statuses[i] }}" 
        *ngFor="let comment of actualComments; let i = index;">

      <div style="...">
        <b>{{comment.iro}}</b> válasza, ekkor: {{comment.mikor}} {{comment.leir}}
      </div>
      <br/>

      <div class="row" style="width:120px;">
        <div style="...">
          <button class="btn btn-light" 
                  id="buttonTarget1" 
                  (click)="statuses[i] = 'accept'; acceptAnswer(comment.iro,comment.mikor,comment.leir)">
            +
          </button>
        </div>
        <div style="...">
          <button class="btn btn-light" 
                  id="buttonTarget2" 
                  (click)="statuses[i] = 'clear'; clearAnswer(comment.iro,comment.mikor,comment.leir)">
            C
          </button>
        </div>
        <div style="...">
          <button class="btn btn-light" 
                  id="buttonTarget3" 
                  (click)="statuses[i] = 'deny'; denyAnswer(comment.iro,comment.mikor,comment.leir)">
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this way each `li` element will get CSS class ('accept', 'deny' or 'clear'). I made it inline within each button `(click)` function, it also could be dome in the TS file.

Now just add some SCSS:

```
li {
  &.accept {
    color: white;
    background: green;
  }
  &.deny,
  &.clear {
    color: white;
    background: red;
  }
}
```

or CSS:

```
li.accept {
  color: white;
  background: green;
}
li.deny,
li.clear {
  color: white;
  background: red;
}
```

If you need to isolate `li`'s selection, you may add its ID to each `li`, like `li#colorTarget`

Now, in you TS file you do not need to deal with styling:

```
acceptAnswer(iro, mikor, iras) {
  var x = this.answerid(iro, mikor, iras);         
  this.actualComments[x].accepted = 1;
}
```

**UPDATE**

you wrote:

> actualComment.accepted represent the accept/deny/clear colors

if I understand correctly, `actualComment.accepted` will have an integer representing one of three colors. If this is correct, let's assume 1 is green (accepted), 2 and 3 are red (deny and clear). In this case you could only change `li` from my original answer to:

```
<li id="colorTarget" 
        class="list-group-item" 
        [class.accept]="comment.accepted === 1"
        [class.deny]="comment.accepted === 2"
        [class.clear]="comment.accepted === 3" 
        *ngFor="let comment of actualComments">
```

or add public `statusesMap` (or ENUM) to your ts file:

```
statusesMap = {
  1: 'accept',
  2: 'deny',
  3: 'clear'
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<li id="colorTarget" 
        class="list-group-item {{ statusesMap[comment.accepted] }}" 
        *ngFor="let comment of actualComments">
```

Comment: I see, thanks, but the CSS gives me errors like : { expected, } expected, at-rule or selector expected. And in the HTML "status is not defined"

Comment: What I wrote is a SCSS not CSS, what are you using? I updated my answer with CSS only code

Comment: I see. It IS working, and it IS easier then before, so thank you, but this way if you click to any of the buttons, the accept deny or clear will apply to all of the rows. Not just the selected.

Comment: I was working on something, but I like this solution better than where I was going.

Comment: my mistake I was going to use `comment` object during iteration and add `status` property on it if possible. Another solution would be to use iteration index (I updated my answer with this solution)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

Updated template. Added a `div`, and moved the `*ngFor` to it to allow me to grab the data needed to create the `id`. The `createId` function build the `id` based on values used.

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="list-group">
    <div *ngFor="let comment of actualComments">
    <li [id]="createId(comment.iro,comment.mikor,comment.leir)" class="list-group-item">
        <div>
            <b>{{comment.iro}}</b> válasza, ekkor: {{comment.mikor}} {{comment.leir}}
        </div>
        <br/>
        …

    </li>
    </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Addition to the component to create the `id`. This is used in the template above.

```
createId(iro, mikor, leir) {
    return `${iro}${mikor}${leir}`;
}
```

Update to `acceptAnswer` function to use the new id created using the new `createId` function.

```
acceptAnswer(iro, mikor, iras) {
    const x = this.answerid(iro, mikor, iras);
    this.actualComments[x].accepted = 1;
    const target = document.getElementById(this.createId(iro, mikor, iras));
    target.style.background = 'green';
    target.style.color = 'white';
}
```